# What in the world does a ^= operator do?

Tags: c#, operators, permutation

I am looking at a permutation code and trying to understand how it does what it does, but one operation has me at a loss: `^=`. Google will not let me search these characters, so can anyone tell me what it's doing, what does this operator mean? You can see an example of it below. Thank you!

```
private void swap(ref char a, ref char b)
{
    if (a == b)
        return;
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

Comment: [`^=` Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx)

Comment: *Google will not let me search these characters* - But you know it's an operator, and there aren't that many operators to look through if you find a complete list.

Comment: Tip: don't swap two char variables like that.  It's a nice exercise to see how the XOR operator works, but using an intermediate variable is a far nicer way to do an actual swap.

Answer (score 5):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx):
An expression of the form

```
x ^= y
```

is evaluated as

```
x = x ^ y
```

**except that x is only evaluated once**. So, if your `x` is a property, it will be called once to `get` and once to `set` the value.

The [`^` (`XOR`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator performs a bitwise `exclusive-OR` operation on integral operands and logical `exclusive-OR` on bool operands (sum on modulus `2`):

```
false ^ false = false;
false ^ true = true;
true ^ false = true;
true ^ true = false;
```

`XOR` operator is quite useful in cryptography as the main it's property is that

```
a ^ b ^ a == b;
```

So your code is simply add the values for a two variables so they are swaped.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "x is only evaluated once" please? I would have thought in your example `x = x ^ y`that x and y would be evaluated, and then XORed and then the result of that assigned to x. I would only call that evaluating it once and assigning it once. And I'm not sure how you could actually evaluate it any more times really... I've noted thanks to the edit that this is actually MS's words. If you have any explanation though I'd be interested. :)

Comment: @Chris See the MSDN article, can't provide you any details right now. Try to investigate the `IL` code.

Comment: @VMAtm if you can't provide any details why you emphasized **except that x is only evaluated once** with bold?

Comment: @Chris For the "only evaluated once" part of the MSDN text, it's useful when for example you have something like `anArray[aFunction()] ^= 2;` (it won't call aFunction() two times)

Comment: @Chris I think that the investigation should be done in case of cascaded expressions, something like `z ^= x^= y`, but still can't get a `IL` example for such situation.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel see the @ ken2k answer

Comment: @VMAtm I'm already aware of that. My point is when you give some emphasis you should be in a position to explain your emphasis. Otherwise, don't emphasis.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel This is a SO - always will be a person who can add something for any answer.

Comment: @ken2k: Ah yes, I was thinking that if x was being assigned to it must be a simple reference for some reason. It seems I just entirely forgot how to program. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*a ^= b* stores in *a* the value of *a^b*, which is the exclusive-or of *a* and *b*.

Comment: Okay, so could you give me an example please?

Comment: @Volearix : say a is 6 (binary 0110), b is 12 (1100), a ^=b will set a to 10 (1010), a having its bits set to 1 only where one bit (of a or b) was previously set.

Answer (score 2):

It's the exclusive-OR assignment operator.

You can learn more here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The exclusive-OR assignment operator.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx